# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

```
>>> class student:
    def _init_(self,name,age):
        self.name
        self.age
    def display(self):
        return("this is a "+self.name+str(self.age))
>>> stu=student("chad",14)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I want to know where I went wrong and how can I  resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__()` is a dunder.  It starts and ends with `__`, a double underbar, aka: dunder.  Change `_init_` to `__init__`.

#### Code:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def display(self):
        return ("this is a " + self.name + str(self.age))

stu = student("chad", 14)
print(stu.display())
```

#### Results:

```
this is a chad14
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class student:
  def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age  

  def display(self):
    stu=student("chad",14)
    print("this is a "+(stu.name)+str(stu.age))

s = student(None,None)
s.display()
```

Comment: 0
down vote
favorite

>>> class student:
    def _init_(self,name,age):
        self.name
        self.age
    def display(self):
        return("this is a "+self.name+str(self.age))
>>> stu=student("chad",14)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: where I done a mistake in my program..coz I want to know with return type

Comment: "init" method should have two "_" in both sides.

Comment: and in inti method you should assign those parameter variables to your class variables. if not it doesn't work because there is nothing assign to them to return. and when returning if you want to print the returning content you have to use print method.try this ->                                     class student:
  def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    
  def display(self):
    return("this is a "+self.name+str(self.age)) 
    
stu = student('cha',14)
print(stu.display())

Comment: import re
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url="http:google.com"
>>> stock=input("enter your search :")
enter your search :Fb
>>> url=url+stock
>>> data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    data=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 524, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1241, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>

Comment: do anyone know about this

Answer (score 0):

Just put a **new line** after the class definition.
Also, I solved some errors in your code.

```py
>>> class student:
...     def __init__(self,name,age):
...         self.name
...         self.age
...     def display(self):
...         return("this is a " + self.name + str(self.age))
...
>>> stu=student("chad",14)
```